# Hitting TooManyRequests 429 when using GoogleCloudStorageComposeOperator

Tags: google-cloud-storage, airflow, google-cloud-composer

When using `GoogleCloudStorageComposeOperator` in Google's Cloud Composer we've started hitting `TooManyRequests`, HTTP 429.

> The rate of change requests to the object path/file.csv exceeds the rate limit. Please reduce the rate of create, update, and delete requests.

What limit are we hitting? I think it's this limit but I'm not sure:

> There is a write limit to the same object name of once per second, so rapid writes to the same object name won't scale.

Does anyone have a sane way around this issue? On retry it usually works, but would be neat to not rely on it working on retry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say, without details, but this is rather Storage than Composer Issue. It is described in [Troubleshooting guide for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/troubleshooting#rate-limit).

There you can find some more references to dig more about it. On [Quotas and Limit](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas#bandwidth) page I have found:

> When a project's bandwidth exceeds quota in a location, requests to
> affected buckets can be rejected with a retryable 429 error or can be
> throttled. See Bandwidth usage for information about monitoring your
> bandwidth.

It seems that this error is intended to be retried, so I think implementation of try/catch mechanism might be a solution.

Comment: Yeah, not really a composer issue, maybe a potential issue with the operator, as it seems to be potentially hitting a limit (might be due to other concurrent jobs hitting the same project), but probably just best to not structure the data in the bucket in a way that the operator isn't idempotent. Thanks for finding the 429 at least!

Comment: While answering the original question it doesn't actually solve one of my problems. One problem was that we got duplicate results after running the compose operator twice, and that's best solved by not storing data the way that we did. The other is that Sentry receives an error when the 429 occurs. Might just have to patch the operator.